# Example of 2 random variables s.t. $(X+Y)$ ~ $U(0,2)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence, uniform-distribution

In my book I found:

> Can you give an example of 2 random variables $X,Y$ S.T $(X+Y)$ ~
> $U(0,2)$ and $X,Y$ are not independent.

Any ideas of how I can find such 2 random variabes?

I would prefer if those random variables tell a story so I can relate to the real world, for example selecting number in $[0,1]$ has uniform disturbution of $(0,1)$.

Comment: $X=Y \sim U(0,1)$ works.

Comment: @JoseAvilez but how can I prove they aren't independent (formally) I know it's clear since it's the same random variable but that's not formal...

Comment: $E(XY) = E(X^2) = 1/3$, but $E(X)E(Y) = 1/4$.

Comment: In more detail: $E(XY)=E(X^2)=\int_{0}^{1}x^2 dx=\frac13$, $E(X)=\int_{0}^{1}x dx=\frac12$, and $E(X)E(Y)=E(X)E(X)=\frac12\cdot\frac12=\frac14$

Comment: Thanks, but one problem remains, how did you show that X+Y ~ Uni(0,2)?

Comment: You can also go to the definition of independence: $P(X|Y)= \mathbb{1}_{Y}(x) \neq P(X)$

Comment: @Dan $X=Y \implies X+Y = X + X = 2X \sim U(0,2)$

Comment: @Bey "2∼(0,2) " that's no a trivial claim, no such law...

Comment: @Dan $X\sim U(0,1)$ right? It's just a location-scale transformation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family

Comment: @Dan this works because $X$ and $Y$ always take the same values in each realization: $\forall \omega \in \Omega, X(\omega) = Y(\omega)$

Comment: @Dan \begin{align}
P(2X\le x)&=P\Big( X\le\frac{x}{2}\Big)\\
&=U(0,1)\Big(\frac{x}{2}\Big)\\
&=U(0,2)(x)
\end{align}

Comment: @lonzaleggiera there is no such thing (0,1) in expressions. it means this vaurblae has uniform ditruubtion it's not variable

Comment: @Dan lonzalegiera is using $U(0,1)$ as the CDF of the standard uniform, it is a function (a simple ramp from 0 to 1 over [$0,1]$. All the comments above are sufficient to answer your question. Not sure what the remaining confusion is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $X \sim U(0,1)$ and let $Y = X$. Then I claim that $X+Y \sim U(0,2)$ and that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

If they were independent, $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$; instead, we have:
$$E(XY) = E(X^2) = \int_0^1 x^2 dx = 1/3 \neq 1/4 = E(X)E(Y)$$

To see that $X+Y \sim U(0,2)$, notice that
$$P(X+Y \leq z) = P(2X \leq z) = P(X \leq z/2) = \begin{cases}
0 & z < 0 \\
z/2 & 0 \leq z \leq 2 \\
1 & z > 2
\end{cases}$$
which is the CDF of a $U(0,2)$ random variable.

Answer (score 0):

Per Peter O's suggestion, I am posting an answer to tie together the comments posted below this question.

**Quick/intuitive answer:**

Define $Z:=X+Y$ and let $X=Y$ and $Y\sim U(0,1)$.

We can define two events $X \in B, Y \in A$ for $A,B \subset (0,1)$

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $P(X\in B | Y \in A) = P(X\in B) \;\;\forall A,B \subset (0,1)$

However, this is not true:

$$A\cap B = \emptyset \implies P(X\in B| Y \in A) = 0 \neq P(X\in B)=\text{leb}(B)$$

That addresses independence.

Forthe distribution, I've pointed out that $2X$ is simply a location-scale transformation of $U(0,1)$ and will result in stretching the dentisty to $U(0,2)$